Isolate Handler Listening to a stream in messenger.listen()
My goal is to listen to a stream in a separate isolate. But it seems that i get the data only once, somehow the data stops streaming. I am using Isolate handler flutter plugin to spawn a new Isolate and send some data to it, I then use the data to do a firebase query and listen to the values coming from firebase.
Here is the method I pass when creating my new isolate :
static void entryPoint(Map<String, dynamic> context) async {
  // Calling initialize from the entry point with the context is
  // required if communication is desired. It returns a messenger which
  // allows listening and sending information to the main isolate.

  await Firebase.initializeApp(); 

  final messenger = HandledIsolate.initialize(context);

  getDriverDB(List<dynamic> isolateData){
      print('====================');
  Map<String, dynamic> drivers = {};

  GeoHasher geo = GeoHasher();
    

  const double latMultiplier = 0.0144927536231884;
  const double lonMultiplier = 0.0181818181818182;
  const double factor = 1.24;

  double lowerLat, lowerLon, greaterLat, greaterLon;

  if (isolateData[0].isEmpty && isolateData[1] == false) {
    lowerLat = isolateData[2] - (latMultiplier * factor);
    lowerLon = isolateData[3] - (lonMultiplier * factor);
    greaterLat = isolateData[2] + (latMultiplier * factor);
    greaterLon = isolateData[3] + (lonMultiplier * factor);
  } else if (isolateData[0].isNotEmpty && isolateData[1] == true) {
    lowerLat = isolateData[0]['pick_lat'] - (latMultiplier * factor);
    lowerLon = isolateData[0]['pick_lng'] - (lonMultiplier * factor);
    greaterLat = isolateData[0]['pick_lat'] + (latMultiplier * factor);
    greaterLon = isolateData[0]['pick_lng'] + (lonMultiplier * factor);
  } else {
    lowerLat = 0.0;
    lowerLon = 0.0;
    greaterLat = 0.0;
    greaterLon = 0.0;
  }

  var lower = geo.encode(lowerLon, lowerLat);
  var higher = geo.encode(greaterLon, greaterLat);

  var fdb = FirebaseDatabase.instance
      .ref('drivers')
      .orderByChild('g')
      .startAt(lower)
      .endAt(higher);

  var d = fdb.onValue;

  d.listen((event) {
    //I wanna listen to a stream here, but the values get posted only once
    print('<<<<<<<<<<<>>>>>>>>>>>');
  });

  }
  

  messenger.listen((data) {
    getDriverDB(data);
  });

  
}

Here is the method that spawns my Isolate :
getDrivers() {
  List<dynamic> data = [];
  bool isAddressListEmpty = addressList.isEmpty;
  data.addAll([userRequestData, isAddressListEmpty]);
  if(!isAddressListEmpty){
    var pickupLocation = addressList.firstWhere((element) => element.type == 'pickup').latlng;
    double pickupLat = pickupLocation.latitude;
    double pickupLong = pickupLocation.longitude;
    data.addAll([pickupLat, pickupLong]);
  }
  
  return  isolates.spawn<Map<String, dynamic>>(entryPoint,
  name: "counter",
    // Executed every time data is received from the spawned isolate.
    onReceive: setCounter,
    // Executed once when spawned isolate is ready for communication.
    onInitialized: () => isolates.send(data, to: "counter"));
}

I tried to listen to the stream outside messenger.listen()

Update! While i thought the issue was execution flow of my code leading to my stream being called once, turns out that the stream wasn't receiving updates from Firebase.‍♂️. Isolate handler works incredibly well with isolate-isolate communication and using plugins that implement native code.
